# VSCode. Run integrated terminal with command like autorun

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I use the atom editor with the 'terminal plus' package, and this autorun command for terminal (PowerShell):

```
cd .venv\Scripts\; .\activate; cd ../../src
```

This command activates virtual environment and return to src folder.

I don't find an option for autorun in VSCode, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with virtualenv but the following command worked for me.

`cd src; code index.js; cd public; cd ../..;`

You don't need any extension for performing this autorun command.VSCode terminal already has this feature in built.

[You can check here for all the features of Integrated Terminal in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal)

Comment: Question about how run. Where you add this command? Can you add correct line from settings file.

Comment: you can just paste it in that terminal and it will works just fine

Comment: sounds not like "auto"